# What is the better and efficient way to remove braces and brackets from stringify array of object in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Below is my code for removing curly braces and square brackets from stringify array of object in JavaScript. I just want to know how can I make this function more efficient.

```
function replaceStrSmCity(str){
    str = str.replace('[','');
    str = str.replace(/{/g,'');
    str = str.replace(']','');
    str = str.replace(/}/g,'');
    return str;
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's the use of this type of function?

Comment: @snapjs Actually, I want to show my array element in CSV in file in one column and when I stringify the array it comes with curly braces and brackets

Comment: @MayurPardeshi Nope. For that, you should use a proper CSV encoder. Removing all brackets and braces from a line will also destroy any string values that contain them.

Comment: @Bergi Thank you for advice I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose this would be more-efficient:

```
function replaceStrSmCity(str){
    return str.replace(/[\[\]\{\}]/g, '');
}
```

It seems like this could remove things unexpectedly though, as these characters could appear in the JSON content.

Comment: Yeah perhaps manually writing a custom serializer for this data is best, instead of trying to clean up the default JSON serializer.